# Does Azure support Microsoft Data Services?

Tags: azure

I am interested in deploying a cloud MDM instance with Azure and MDS.  What version SQL Server does Azure offer?  Is there a version that supports Microsoft Data Services?  If not, then is this on the roadmap? When would this be available?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about SQL Database (previously known as SQL Azure), it is based on SQL Server 2008 Core and lots of new components from recently released SQL Server 2012 however MDS pieces is not fully available in Windows Azure SQL Database. Learn more about Windows Azure SQL Database [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336256).

However you can choose [Windows Azure Virtual Machine (Preview)](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/) in which you can build your own Windows Server 2008 based Virtual Machine and run SQL Server 2012 on it and this way you could use MDS without any issue. IF you want to use MDS, this would be an ideal solution. Not only that, you can get a Windows Azure Virtual Machine running SQL Server 2012 (eval) in about 5 minutes.